# How to dynamically update ListView height while keeping the ScrollViewer enabled?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, scrollview, uwp-xaml

ListView is placed inside UserControl which is set in parent XAML to asterix "*" height.
I want to use ListView with possibility to scroll items, when there are items that exceed ListView. It should work for different size of window.

It works fine when I set Grid's RowDefinitions with fixed integer, but when I try to use asterix "*" ScrollViewer disables.

I also tried to bind and update RowDefinition's height via some code behind in overriden MeasureOverride method, but it didn't work as expected.

Here is code inside my UserControl:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentArea"
          Background="{StaticResource MixerBackground}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{x:Bind ListViewHeight}" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Source,Mode=TwoWay}"
            CanDragItems="True"
            CanReorderItems="True"
            AllowDrop="True"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Track">
                    <Grid
                        Background="LightGray"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{x:Bind Id}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="24"
                            Margin="20,5,20,5"/>

                        <Grid
                            Background="Black"
                            Width="500"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Grid.Column="1">
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I expect to get the ScrollViewer working correctly, but ListView stay at the old size or scroll bar is disabled - depending on Height value.

Is there any way to achieve dynamically resizing ListView with scroll?

**Edit**

Here is parent Page XAML code which is loaded into Frame via Light MVVM framework:

```
<Grid
        x:Name="ContentArea">
        <Grid
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <maineditor:MainEditorMenuControl x:Name="ProjectMenu" />
            <maineditor:MainEditorWorkspaceControl x:Name="Workspace" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <maineditor:MainEditorMixerControl x:Name="Mixer" Grid.Row="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

[image: How it looks now, and also after trying Nico solution (image)]

**Edit 2**
I think the problem may be connected with MVVM template I've created with Windows Template Studio plugin for Visual Studio. If I try to recreate minimal solution from scratch with all properties 1:1 as in my app it works in fresh project, but not in mine.

Comment: Unfortunately it still don't work in my source app. (See update and other comment)

Comment: Have you tried  to  use `RelativePanel` as root layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to dynamically update ListView height while keeping the ScrollViewer enabled?

If you want make `RowDefinition` height same as the `ListView`, you could give the ListView a name and use `{Binding ElementName=MyListView,Path=ActualHeight}`syntax to bind both height property.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=MyListView,Path=ActualHeight}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView
    Name="MyListView"
    CanDragItems="True"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    AllowDrop="True"
    Loaded="MyListView_Loaded"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid
                Background="LightGray"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                BorderBrush="Black">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="24"
                    Margin="20,5,20,5"/>

                    <Grid
                    Background="Black"
                    Width="500"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Grid.Column="1">
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Scroll bar is disabled all the time. I think it's because default ListViewHeight is inherited from parent or autoset.

Comment: @multim,I have test in my side it works, could you mind provide a demo could reproduce this issue for us. I will test it.

Comment: @multim, If your project is non-public, please avoid share link here!

Comment: The problem is when I start new project from scratch with minimal code, the problem doesn't occur. The mimal demo solution will be UWP Light MVVM template and this page with user control.

Comment: I found the problem, there was an error in MeasureOverride method which caused keeping ActualHeight property at fixed rate. After correcting this your solution works fine.